# Checkear si un usuario o email ya existe

Tags: php

tengo un sistema de login que va por mysql. El problema es que si creas un usuario con un nombre igual o un email igual al que ya hay en la base de datos se duplica.
El register es este

```
  require 'database.php';

  $message = '';
  if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, user) VALUES (:email, :password, :user)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']) {
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    } else {
        $error = 'password';
    }

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    } else {
        if($error=="password"){
            $message = 'Credentials does not match';
        } else {
            $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
        }

    }
  }
```

y el login este

```
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: Censurado');
  }
  require 'database.php';
  if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, user, email, password, rank FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message = '';
    if (count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])) {
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
      header("Location: Censurado");
    } else {
      $message = 'Sorry, those credentials do not match';
    }
  }
```

Un saludo y agradeceria mucho la ayuda :)

---

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentitites($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\''; 
    $records = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if( !count($results) ) {
          require 'database.php';
            $message = '';
            if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, user) VALUES (:email, :password, :user)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
            if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']) {
                $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
            } else {
                $error = 'password';
            }
    }
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $message = 'Successfully created new user';
        } else {
            if($error=="password"){
                $message = 'Credentials does not match';
            } else if($error=="exist") {
                $message = 'Account alredy exist';
            } else {
                $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
            }

    }
```

Asi es como deje el código

---

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';
  $message = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentitites($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\''; 
        $records = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if( !count($results) ) {
            require 'database.php';
            $message = '';
            if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, user) VALUES (:email, :password, :user)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
            }
            if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']) {
                $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
            } else {
                $error = 'password';
            }
        }
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $message = 'Successfully created new user';
            } else {
                if($error=="password"){
                    $message = 'Credentials does not match';
                } else if($error=="exist") {
                    $message = 'Account alredy exist';
                } else {
                    $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

No funciona. Primero la sintaxis estaba mal. Al arreglarla me encuentro con este error

```
[03-Mar-2019 19:37:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function htmlentitites() in url censurada/api_managecredentials.php on line 25
```

La linea 25 es está `$sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentitites($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\'';`  ya que aquí no he escrito todo el código.
Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

--- ACTUALIZACIÓN
El error erra que htmlentitites se escribe htmlentities

Comment: Sé que esto no está relacionado con la pregunta en sí, pero ha sido una sorpresa agradable ver que alguien pregunta por un sistema de login y está usando sentencias preparadas (sin nada de `mysql_*` a la vista) y hasheado de contraseñas. Quizás una cosa que le faltaría para que fuera perfecta (y puede que lo tengas pero no lo hayas copiado) sería usar [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-regenerate-id.php) para regenerar el id  de sesión después de cada transición en su estado.

Comment: Casi casi, pero verificar que el email y el usuario ya existen lo deberías solucionar restringiendolos como UNIQUE ya que en realidad no deberían existir 2 email iguales, mucho menos 2 usuarios... y también hacer la verificación con un procedimiento almacenado para evitar ciertos procesos a tu sistema web y dejarselos para que  tu gestor se encargue... Si no trabajas a nivel de base de datos harías que todo dependa de tu código en php.

Comment: StackOverflow no es un foro donde vas añadiendo respuestas y más respuestas añadiendo tus avances y nuevas dudas; StackOverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde hay una sección para la pregunta y otra para las respuestas, y las preguntas deben ser únicas, sin cambiarlas dependiendo de cómo de avanzado vayas (porque puedes dejar respuestas que eran válidas sin sentido). Si tienes una nueva duda, debes crear una nueva pregunta. Lee [ask] y [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo del **register** debe agregar un codigo extra que valide la existencia del correo electronico en tu base de datos, osease, deberas hacer una consulta para buscar el correo y de existir resultados pues ya harias lo que indica tu linea 5 en adelante.

Deberas agregar antes de la linea 5 lo siguiente:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\''; 
    $records = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if( !count($results) ) {
    ...... todo el demas codigo.....
    }
}
```

Comment: No me funciona  :(.

Comment: la funcion htmlentities() ya la corregi... errata de escritura !